# Powershell - parsing a PDF file for a literal or image

Tags: excel, powershell, pdf, search, ms-word

Using Powershell & running PowerGUI.  I have a PDF file that I need to search through in order to find if there was an attachment referenced within the content of a particular page.  Either that, or I need to search for images, such as a Microsoft Word or Excel icon or a PDF icon within the document.

I am using the following code to read in the page:

```
Add-Type -Path "c:\itextsharp-all-5.4.5\itextsharp-dll-core\itextsharp.dll"
$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList "c:\files\searchfile.pdf"

for ($page = 1; $page -le 3; $page++) {
 $lines = [char[]]$reader.GetPageContent($page) -join "" -split "`n"
 foreach ($line in $lines) {
  if ($line -match "^\[") {   
   $line = $line -replace "\\([\S])", $matches[1]
   $line -replace "^\[\(|\)\]TJ$", "" -split "\)\-?\d+\.?\d*\(" -join ""
  }
 }
}
```

However, the above gives a few bits of text, but mostly unprintable characters.

How can you search a PDF file using Powershell searching for either a literal (like ".doc" or ".xlsx")?  Can a PDF be searched for a graphic (like the Excel or Word icon)?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the PDF raw content, it's not easy to give specific help, so if you can share a sample PDF or it's contents that would be helpful.

Once you know what to look for in the stream, you can search by reading in the file line by line and using the `-match` operator:

```
$file = [io.file]::ReadAllLines('C:\test​.pdf')
$title = ($file -match "<rdf:li")[0].Split(">")[1].Split("<")[0]
$description = ($file -match "<rdf:li")[2].Split(">")[1].Split("<")[0]
write-host ("Title: " + $title)
write-host ("Description: " + $description)
```

I doubt very much that the contents of the file will tell you much more than that an image exists at particular page coordinates (although I'm by no means a PDF expert) but it may also include the binary file stream, in which case you may be able to save that stream as a file (I haven't tried it as yet).